Undetermined value of vector element accessed by pointer
Problem
I have two structs: the first has data in an array and in a vector; the second gives access to the pointers to those data as pArr = &array[0] or pVec = &vector[0]. Next, I may obtain different values of pVec[0] depending on how pVec was produced. However, pArr always works as expected.
Code to reproduce
I use Visual Studio 2017.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


struct InnerClass {

    InnerClass(int _n) : n(_n) {
        arr = new int[n];
        for (int i{ 0 }; i < n; ++i) {
            vec.push_back(i);
            arr[i] = i;
        }
    }

    const int* get_pointer_to_vector_begining() const {
        return &vec[0];
    }

    const int* get_pointer_to_array_begining() const {
        return &arr[0];
    }

    int n;
    int* arr;
    std::vector<int> vec;
};


struct OuterClass {

    int n;
    InnerClass* inner;

    OuterClass(int _n) : n(_n) {
        inner = new InnerClass(n);
    }

    const int* get_vector_of_member() const {
        return inner->get_pointer_to_vector_begining();
    }

    const int* get_array_of_member() const {
        return inner->get_pointer_to_array_begining();
    }

    const int* get_vector_of_new_object() const {
        //const InnerClass* sub = new InnerClass(n);
        const InnerClass& sub(n);// = new InnerClass(n);
        return sub.get_pointer_to_vector_begining();
    }

    const int* get_array_of_new_object() const {
        const InnerClass& sub(n);
        return sub.get_pointer_to_array_begining();
    }

    const int* get_vector_of_new_object_by_pointer() const {
        const InnerClass* sub = new InnerClass(n);
        return sub->get_pointer_to_vector_begining();
    }

    const int* get_array_of_new_object_by_pointer() const {
        const InnerClass* sub = new InnerClass(n);
        return sub->get_pointer_to_array_begining();
    }
};

int main() {

    OuterClass mc(10);

    const int *pArrMember = mc.get_array_of_member();
    const int *pVecMember = mc.get_vector_of_member();
    const int *pArrNewObject = mc.get_array_of_new_object();
    const int *pVecNewObject = mc.get_vector_of_new_object();
    const int *pArrNewObjectByPointer = mc.get_array_of_new_object_by_pointer();
    const int *pVecNewObjectByPointer = mc.get_vector_of_new_object_by_pointer();
    

    int i = 1;
    std::cout << "pArr[" << i << "]: "
        << pArrMember[i] << " "
        << pArrNewObject[i] << " "
        << pArrNewObjectByPointer[i]
        << std::endl; // expected value: 1

    std::cout << "pVec[" << i << "]: "
        << pVecMember[i] << " "
        << pVecNewObject[i] << " " 
        << pVecNewObjectByPointer[i] << " "
        << std::endl; // expected value: 1
    

    return 0;
}

Output:
pArr[1]: 1 1 1
pVec[1]: 1 -842150451 1

So pVecNewObject[i] is either 1 or something weird,
while the others (pArrMember[i] and pVecNewObjectByPointer[i]) are always 1.
Question
Could anyone make me understand where the root of the problem is?
P.S.
I came across this behavior working with SFML Image::getPixelsPtr() function. There I got access violation trying to access something like pVec[0]. I found a workaround, though the problem mechanism is remaining vague to me. I feel I missed something basic in here.

OuterClass::get_vector_of_new_object returns a dangling pointer - a pointer into the vector that is destroyed when the InnerClass instance goes out of scope at the closing brace of get_vector_of_new_object. The reason the array works is because you are leaking it - InnerClass allocates the array on the heap and never destroys it.

Can you explain what you expect and what you actually get?  "However, pArr always works as expected." - is a very vague issue description.

So I also leak the dynamically allocated Inner instance in 'get_vector_of_new_object_by_pointer', and it survives upon return...

"depending on how pVec was produced." -- What are the ways in which pVec can be produced? One could read through your code, but that's unreliable and of no use to someone searching for this question. You should add text to your question describing the ways (as you understand them).

Yes. Pointers to objects, or subobjects of objects, that you leak never become dangling, because, well, you leak them and so they are never destroyed.

@pch const InnerClass& sub(n); -- So in general, was your expectation that somehow this local variable would "survive", just because you are returning a pointer to its internals?  If so, C++ does not work this way.  -- Could anyone make me understand where the root of the problem is? -- I believe the entire issue boils down to not fully understand variable lifetimes in C++.

@pch pVec[1]: 1 -842150451 1 -- Here is the problem with writing code to prove or disprove how C++ behaves.  What if that middle value was 1?  You would have concluded that there is nothing wrong with returning a pointer to a local variable.  The proper way to learn C++ is to know the rules of the language -- most of time, you can't simply write code and conclude "this is how C++ works".  In other computer languages, you may be able to get away with learning those languages in this fashion, but C++ is a different story.

If you have them available, turn on a few sanitizers: https://godbolt.org/z/vd35n46zq . If you don't have them available Set up a Linux virtual machine so that you have them available. They are too dang useful to go without.

Thank you guys for this basics for lifetime of variables in c++. I have little practice in c++, and the explanation of so obvious to me.

@PaulMcKenzie That was it! First, I dealt with much more involved code using SFML and FFMpeg. It worked as if no destruction of local scope variable took place, that is the correct data were accessible via the pointer. However, at sun some time I faced with access violation and didn't link this with correctly destructed data. To sum up, this is a short story of how I realized that the code worked the exact way I programed it, and not the way I expected.

As mentioned in a comment this can be boiled down to understanding lifetime.
Consider this much simpler example:
struct foo {
    int * x = new int[42];
    int y = 42;
};

foo misses to correctly implement the rule of 3/5/0. x is allocated via new but the class misses to delete it. It will be leaked. y is fine with the rule of 0. It will be properly cleaned up when a foo is destroyed. Now if you are doing something like this:
std::pair<int*,int*> boo() {
     foo f;
     return { f.x , &(f.y) };
};

Then f has automatic storage duration. It will be destroyed when boo returns. When f is destroyed there won't be any y member anymore. It will be gone. The array on the other hand, will still exist in memory. f merely holds a pointer to that array. Destroying a pointer does not affect the pointee. f getting destroyed will not affect the array. The function returns a pointer that points to an array and another pointer that is dangling, that points to a no longer existing int. Dereferencing that pointer is undefined.
I'll leave it to you to apply this to your code. Your many different functions are really just variations of the above.
Note that if your code has undefined behavior then even getting a 1 as output when you expected a 1 as output does not imply that everything is ok. You cannot distinguish a good 1 from a 1 that just happened to be in some place in memory by chance.

Thank you for your reply. I got it in the comments above. This is the basic thing, however I missed it.

formally  int y = 42; is fitting into "rule 3/5", it's no longer a "0" because structure isn't trivial.
